# Autoencoder MaxUnpool2d missing 'Indices' argument

Tags: pytorch

The following model returns the error: 
**TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'indices'**

I've exhausted many online examples and they all look similar to my code. My maxpool layer returns both the input and the indices for the unpool layer. Any ideas on what's wrong?

```
class autoencoder(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(autoencoder, self).__init__()
    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        ...
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=1, return_indices=True)
    )
    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.MaxUnpool2d(2, stride=1),
        ...
    )

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.encoder(x)
    x = self.decoder(x)
    return x
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53858626/pytorch-convolutional-autoencoders?rq=1), the solution seems to be to separate the maxunpool layer from the decoder and explicitly pass its required parameters. `nn.Sequential` only takes one parameter.

```
class SimpleConvAE(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    # input: batch x 3 x 32 x 32 -> output: batch x 16 x 16 x 16
    self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        ...
        nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2, return_indices=True),
    )

    self.unpool = nn.MaxUnpool2d(2, stride=2, padding=0)

    self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
        ...
    )

def forward(self, x):
    encoded, indices = self.encoder(x)
    out = self.unpool(encoded, indices)
    out = self.decoder(out)
    return (out, encoded)
```

Comment: Hey, your answer was very helpful in understanding the issue! I wouldn't have figured out the thing I wrote as secondary answer without yours, so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I wrapped both the `MaxPool2d` and the `MaxUnpool2d` into custom classes. Now I **can use them in `Sequential`**.

It is probably not the most elegant solution, but it does seem to work:

```py
class MaxPool2dIndexExtractor(nn.MaxPool2d):

    def __init__(self, segnetlite, kern, stride):
        super().__init__(kern, stride, return_indices=True)
        self.segnetlite = [segnetlite]

    def forward(self, x):
        output, indices = super().forward(x)
        self.segnetlite[0].pool_indices += [indices]
        return output

class MaxUnpool2dIndexConsumer(nn.MaxUnpool2d):

    def __init__(self, segnetlite, kern, stride):
        super().__init__(kern, stride)
        self.segnetlite = [segnetlite]

    def forward(self, x):
        indices = self.segnetlite[0].pool_indices.pop()
        return super().forward(x, indices)
```

These classes take an additional parameter on construction: something that they should store the indices in or get them back from again. In my case, I called it `segnetlite` here (just because of my use case. You can call it whatever you want!) and made sure it had an empty list as an attribute.

You could also adapt this code to directly use a list.

Something important to be aware of is that if `segnetlite` is a module and you save it to `self.segnetlite` directly, pytorch would enter infinite recursion on `train()` because it would walk circles while trying to list all the nested modules. This is why I have saved the `segnetlite` object inside a list here.

The way I am using these classe here is inside some `Sequential()`s. First I have one that does some downscaling. Later I have a different one that does some upscaling. In the second `Sequential`, I have the unpooling that correspond to the pooling in the first one - but in reverse order. This is why the `MaxUnpool2dIndexConsumer` `pop()`s from the back of the list.